# Excel quick access toolbar - run macro from active instead of previous workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom button (not an add-in, just a "shortcut" button) in Excel's quick access toolbar to run a macro in the active workbook. The workbook is modified and saved daily with a new filename. When the link is first created in the active workbook (call it Version 1) the macro runs fine. However the following day (filename now Version 2) clicking on the macro button opens workbook Version 1 and runs the macro saved in Version 1.

Is there a simple way to break the link and run the macro in the most recent active workbook?

The code is basic - it just opens up a userform and is saved in "ThisWorkbook"

```
Sub OPEN_DATA_USERFORM()

ufDATA.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Seeing the code would help.  Is the custom button in an add-in, or in each workbook?

Comment: So your macro includes opening that file and then running some commands in it? Consider placing all of these workbooks in the same folder and have VBA open the most recently saved (= newest) one.

Comment: Yes, the button in the quick access ribbon runs the short bit of code which opens a userform. The userform can then run other macros. The workbooks are saved in the same folder, I just want the code to open the userform in the active workbook and not in a previously saved one.

Comment: hello, just as a suggestion, can you put a button in the worksheet and assign the macro to that button instead of ribbon? :)

Comment: That is what I have been doing, but to clean up the workspace and make the code accessible from every sheet I prefer to run the macro from an icon in the quick access toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to guide you through this, I hope it helps.

What we need to do is we need to call `OPEN_DATA_USERFORM()` from our "PERSONAL.XLSB" file. In VB editor screen, in the project explorer you will find a file called "PERSONAL.XLSB", you need to add an "Module" to that and add following code:

```
Sub KickOff()
    Call Application.Run(Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!OPEN_DATA_USERFORM")
End Sub
```

By this we will be able to call the userform.show function from our PERSONAL.XLSB which is always running in the background when you open the excel.

PS: I am assuming your `OPEN_DATA_USERFORM()` is coded in your daily workbook.

UPDATE: PERSONAL.XLSB
Your file should be visible in your project explorer like below:

[image]

If it is not there record a dummy macro and select your personal file like below then it should appear in your project explorer in VBA screen:

[image]

Comment: Dubison thanks for the suggestion, but I have never seen a file called PERSONAL.XLSB. I only see ms excel objects, Forms, Modules and Class Modules in my VB editor. Can you give me some more directions?

Comment: Thanks Dubison, but I get a Run-time error '1004' .....the macro may not be available in that workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: the macro I have provided should be in PERSONAL.XLSB and your button should be linking to that one. Beside your original macro should be in your userform file. Beside that you may need to restart excel so it will probably ask if you want to enable macros or not.

Comment: your method works but I decided to simply create a backup each day instead of saving as a new file with a new name. That way the path to the macro shouldn't change.